# How to use countifs code with a date range

Tags: excel, vba

I would like the below code to only count data from last month if possible. The date is in Column I and is dd/mm/yyyy format. I would also like to make other macros with the same code for this month and the last quarter if possible, thanks in advance.

```
    Private Sub Count_KPI11()
    With Sheets("Last Mth Processed")
    .Range("E5").Value = CountA("Work", "WSCA1", "Processed")
    .Range("E6").Value = CountA("Work", "WSCA2", "Processed")
    .Range("E7").Value = CountA("Work", "SECA11", "Processed")
    .Range("E8").Value = CountA("Work", "SECA12", "Processed")
    .Range("E9").Value = CountA("Work", "SECA13", "Processed")
    .Range("E17").Value = CountA("Work", "NWCA5", "Processed")
    .Range("E18").Value = CountA("Work", "NWCA6A", "Processed")
    .Range("E19").Value = CountA("Work", "NWCA6B", "Processed")
    .Range("E20").Value = CountA("Work", "NWCA7", "Processed")
    .Range("E21").Value = CountA("Work", "NWCA8", "Processed")
    .Range("E22").Value = CountA("Work", "NWCA9", "Processed")
    .Range("E23").Value = CountA("Work", "NWCA10A", "Processed")
    .Range("E24").Value = CountA("Work", "NWCA10B", "Processed")
    .Range("E32").Value = CountA("Work", "WSCA3", "Processed")
    .Range("E33").Value = CountA("Work", "WSCA4", "Processed")
    .Range("E34").Value = CountA("Work", "SECA14", "Processed")
    .Range("E35").Value = CountA("Work", "SECA15", "Processed")
    .Range("E36").Value = CountA("Work", "SECA16", "Processed")
    End With
    End Sub
    '  Optional 3rd parameter for PASS/FAIL
    Function CountA(v1 As String, v2 As String, Optional v3 As String = "") As Long
        Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, rng3 As Range
        With Sheets("calculations")

            Set rng1 = .Range("D7:D100000")
            Set rng2 = .Range("L7:L100000")
            Set rng3 = .Range("M7:M100000")
            If Len(v3) > 0 Then
                CountA = Application.CountIfs(rng1, v1, rng2, v2, rng3, v3)
            Else
                CountA = Application.CountIfs(rng1, v1, rng2, v2)
            End If
        End With
    End Function
```

Comment: Your question has quite a bit of ambiguity within it. Still, it looks like you could just adjust your function by adding the new criteria you want to the 'countifs' function.

Comment: @dra. I'm very new to VBA, would you be able to add that to my code so it only counts data from last month?

Comment: I will leave the coding to you but to outline the concept... 
Add your rng4 under rng3 that includes your dates. Then, in CountA = Application.CountIfs(rng1, v1, rng2, v2, rng3, v3,rng4,">="&FirstDayOfLastMonth,rng4,"<" & FirstDayOfThisMonth). Remember your dates are just a serial number so you need to determine the days you are referring to. In excel the criteria looks like: `=COUNTIFS(I8:I100000, ">=" & DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY())-1,1),I8:I100000,"<" & DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()),1)  )` but that will change in VBA. ie today() becomes 'date' etc.

Comment: @dra_red. Thank you, I will see how I go, cheers.